# Django CORS issue with VUE

Tags: python, django, vue.js, cors

I am running python 3.11.3 with the following packages:

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.6.0
Django              4.2.1
django-cors-headers 4.0.0
pip                 23.1.2
setuptools          67.6.1
sqlparse            0.4.4
whitenoise          6.4.0
```

I am trying to enable **CORS** for **Vue**, but I keep running into the following error:

```
Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://127.0.0.1:8090 does not match any
trusted origins.): /api/login/
```

In settings.py, I have:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'reports',
   'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

Browser response header

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:8090
Content-Length: 2569
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Sun, 21 May 2023 08:13:21 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
Vary: origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Request header

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8090
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8090/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Check on which ip your **Django** server and your **VUE** application  is running and inside **VUE** make sure you're hitting correct enpoint.